# Changing geom_text font from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change font/family on text that is generated in geom_text inside a function that returns a ggplot object? In the example below I would to change the font to "Tahoma" in the p1 object.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_fun <- function(){
  
  p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = 1:3), aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_col(fill = 'lightblue') +
    geom_text(aes(label = x), color = 'black')
  
  p
  
}

p1 <- plot_fun()
```

Answer (score 0):

try the `theme()` option, i.e. adding `p <- p + theme(text=element_text(family="Tahoma"))`

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, perhaps move to comments or provide an answer which is reproducible.